# Weird JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript

```
for (var i=a.length-1;i>0;i--) {
    if (i!=a.indexOf(a.charAt(i))) {
        a=a.substring(0,i)+a.substring(i+1);
    }
}
```

I found this in a web app I'm auditing, it just baffles me why it's there.
I can't seem to see a case where `i!=a.indexOf(a.charAt(i))` would be false.

The value the pass to it is:

```
a = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

There is no comment either //sigh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be true for repeated characters, since `indexOf` finds the first index of a string, and you're searching from the end. Example:

```
var a = "xyzxyz";
```

On first iteration, `i === 4`, `a.charAt(4) === "x"`, and `a.indexOf("x") === 0`. So `4 !== 0`.

It then sets `a = a.substring(0, 4) + a.substring(5)`. Recalling at `substring` is inclusive in the first index but exclusive in the last index, that means in this case `a = "xyz" + "yz"`, so we have removed the duplicate `"x"` from the string.

Since the loop traverses backward, this will continue to work even for characters repeated more than once; you can see that the portion `a.substring(i + 1)` will always have been covered by the algorithm already, i.e. not contain any duplicates.

---

As always when encountering this type of thing, applying the *extract method refactoring* would be a great way to make the code clearer. (Even better than commenting it!) So if you just pulled this out into a method, the code could become `a = removeDuplicateChars(a)`, and everyone is much happier.

Comment: Thanks for the extra comments.